# Eclipse CDT shows "unresolved inclussion" Errors though project compiles

Tags: c++, eclipse, indexing, settings, eclipse-cdt

I am using eclipse CDT luna for a C++/C project. I have downloaded from a github and maintaining a local repository. I imported a project to eclipse "existing code a Makefile project". When I build the application once on the command line it compiles and runs and I could also debug the source. What is annoying at the moment is that all most std included and system included shows "unresolved inclusion" error.

I ve changed my toolchain in the project properties to Linux GCC, Cross GCC and to GNU autotools but they wont go aw[image]ay.

I also added following paths to and tried to buld the index but did not work either.[image]

Does anyone has any idea why this happens. Once again I am iterating that project compiles and runs just fine but these markings are really annoying as I can not see breakpoints ect.

std setting of my project properties as follows. [image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse CDT C++11/C++0x support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support)

Comment: I came across this solution before but there are some parts of the code that uses C99 which I have solved as I have indicated in the added image. is it possible for me to have both C++11 and C99 on the same std= setting.

Comment: see [hier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194103/eclipse-cdt-indexer-how-to-solve-unresolved-includes) (answer from Ryan Higgins). It helped in my case.