# Eclipse CDT with MinGW: indexer can't find standard headers

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, mingw-w64

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen CDT on Windows 7 64-bit.  I've got MinGW-W64 installed, in a non-standard location but Eclipse reports that it is correctly found.  But in the project I'm working on (which is a plain Makefile project), lines like

```
#include <string.h>
```

are underlined and marked with a '?' in the margin.  I believe the component responsible is the "indexer".

I can solve the problem by adding the MinGW include path to each project (Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols), but that seems like The Wrong Way To Do It, as I'd have to repeat for every new project.

There doesn't seem to be a global setting though -- nothing in Preferences -> C/C++ -> Indexer, and nothing similar to 'Paths and Symbols' in global preferences.

Can I set the include paths used by the indexer once, so that any project using MinGW will "inherit" them?

Comment: BTW, the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194103/eclipse-cdt-indexer-how-to-solve-unresolved-includes looks related but does not answer my question, as it deals with headers from other projects in the workspace.

Comment: "Eclipse reports that it is correctly found" - where does it report that?

Comment: @HighCommander4 in "New -> Makefile project from existing code", I have "show only available toolchains" checked.  "MinGW GCC" is included in the list.  Also, the docs say one of the ways Eclipse finds MinGW is by ensuring mingw32-gcc.exe is on the system path, which it is.

Answer (score 5):

OK, well I've found what worked for me.  I went to:

```
Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc.
```

And selected the Providers tab.  An entry "CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings MinGW" was present, but was not checked.  I checked this and ensured "Use global provider shared between projects" was checked.  Hit Apply, and every project was magically re-indexed and the headers are now found.

Thanks are due to @HighCommander4's comment which prompted me to poke around the settings a bit more.